# Jupyter Kernel Keeps Dying Trying to Convert Pandas to NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I have the following code I'm trying to run in Jupyter notebook line by line. But it keeps dying as soon as it arrives at the line where the pandas dataframe is being converted to NumPy.

```
#importing libraries
import sqlalchemy
import spacy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#connecting to database and reading into dataframe with sqlalchemy
user_inputs = "SELECT * FROM t1"
rasa_questions = "SELECT * FROM o2"

server = 'DEM'
db = 's'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + server + '/' + db + '?driver=SQL+Server')

user_inputs_df = pd.read_sql_query(user_inputs, engine)
rasa_questions_df = pd.read_sql_query(rasa_questions, engine)

#loading spacy
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")

rasa_questions_list = rasa_questions_df["F"]
user_input_list = user_inputs_df["U"]

rasa_vector = [nlp(s).vector for s in rasa_questions_list]
user_vector = [nlp(s).vector for s in user_input_list]

similarity_scores = np.inner(rasa_vector, user_vector) / (np.linalg.norm(rasa_vector, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(user_vector, axis=1))

data = []
for i in range(len(rasa_questions_list)):
    for j in range(len(user_input_list)):
        data.append([rasa_questions_list[i], user_input_list[j], similarity_scores[i][j]])

O2_Similarity_Scores = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['RASA Frage', 'User Input', 'Similarity Score'])
print(O2_Similarity_Scores)
```

So, this is the line of code that makes the kernel go dead -
similarity_scores = np.inner(rasa_vector, user_vector) / (np.linalg.norm(rasa_vector, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(user_vector, axis=1))

I am on Windows 10 and Python 3.9.12.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Test `np.array(rasa_vector, dtype=float)` and `np.array(user_vector, dtype=float)`.  It's the float array version of thoses lists that you need for those calculations.

Comment: @hpaulj I added 
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True' on top of the code, and this time round didn't get a dead kernel. But now I'm getting another error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 similarity_scores = np.inner(rasa_vector, user_vector) / (np.linalg.norm(rasa_vector, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(user_vector, axis=1))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12234,) (207922,)

Comment: What's the `shape` of the two arrays I asked about.  When you call something `...vector` it should be a 'vector', a numpy array, not some ill defined list of something or other.  `np.norm` and `inner` work with float arrays.  Read their docs to verify what dimension they expect.

Comment: @hpaulj Shapes are respectively (12234, 300) and (300, 207922).
I am then using the line -
similarity_scores = np.matmul(rasa_vector_T, user_vector.T) / (np.linalg.norm(rasa_vector_T, axis=0) * np.linalg.norm(user_vector, axis=1))
But am now receiving error - 
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 207922 is different from 300)

I'm really confused why these are not compatible, but admittedly my knowledge on the topic is severely limited.
Thank you for suggesting the methods that you did.

Comment: `np.matmul` is quite clear about how dimension have to match. The number of columns of `A` must match the number of rows of `B`.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but I think the current shapes of both numpy arrays should be compatible as they are A(12234, 300) and B(300, 207922), so columns for the first are same as rows for the second. I am still getting error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12234, 211537) (300,) and I am so confused. I checked their shapes multiple times too and am just scratching my head as to not being able to see the problem.

Comment: With  A(12234, 300) and B(300, 207922), the matmul result will be  (12234,, 207922).  Do you understand that?  I thought in the previous case that you were apply `T` to those.  `broadcast` error comes from other operations - divide, add, subtract, regular multiply.  You may need to break the long calculation into pieces, and test and check their shapes individually.  Debugging a line with multiple calculations is hard if you can't tell exactly which operation is the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj I broke down the code and now the dot_similarity_scores = np.matmul(rasa_vector, user_vector), rasa_vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(rasa_vector, axis=0),
user_vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(user_vector, axis=1) runs without error. 
Next rasa_vector_norm_2d = np.reshape(rasa_vector_norm, (300, 1))
user_vector_norm_2d = np.reshape(user_vector_norm, (1, 300)) is ok too.
But trying to compute norm_product = rasa_vector_norm_2d * user_vector_norm_2d, getting an error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (300,211537) (12234,300)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding your comment to be readable:

```
dot_similarity_scores = np.matmul(rasa_vector, user_vector) 
rasa_vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(rasa_vector, axis=0) 
user_vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(user_vector, axis=1)
```

runs without error. Next

```
rasa_vector_norm_2d = np.reshape(rasa_vector_norm, (300, 1)) 
user_vector_norm_2d = np.reshape(user_vector_norm, (1, 300))
```

is ok too. But trying to compute

```
norm_product = rasa_vector_norm_2d * user_vector_norm_2d
```

getting an error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (300,211537) (12234,300)
```

That last would be ok for `matmul` with the variables switched, but the shapes are wrong from element-wise multiplication.

But with the previous reshape, those arrays should be (300,1) and (1,300).  With those the '*' would produce a (300,300) result.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to make them run in the end, but am now running out of memory.
data = []
for i in range(len(rasa_questions_list)):
    for j in range(len(user_input_list)):
        data.append([rasa_questions_list[i], user_input_list[j], similarity_scores[i][j]])

O2_Similarity_Scores = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['RASA Frage', 'User Input', 'Similarity Score'])
print(O2_Similarity_Scores)

I used NumPy for efficient speed to begin with but even that is making me run out of memory :(